# Can we get a 2nd favorite tags filter for our areas of expertise?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

Can we get a 2nd favorite tags filter for our areas of expertise?

I want to put these as my favorite tags - javascript, html, css - but I don't want the entire question list to highlight in light yellow. Most of the questions on the list are javascript related.

I've already ignored tags like: c, c++, c#, java, etc... which are more back-end related tags. I've changed them from grayed out to hidden, as I'd never answer those.

What I really want to do is highlight these tags in a brighter color, than the current yellow color: search, bots, crawlers, engines, etc....

Those are the tags, which I have a special interest in... as I'm an expert in those areas. Adding a 3rd tag filter box area could highlight any "expert" or "specialty" tags in a brighter color, than the normal highlighted tag color. It's the difference between lemon yellow & bright highlighter yellow.

I'd prefer to answer the brighter yellow colored questions first, followed by the normal soft yellow highlighted questions second, followed by any white background questions third.

Would this be possible to do?

Comment: You might want to look into the [new-nav](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), where you can create tabs for groups of favorites...

Comment: It looks interesting. I've signed up for that alpha test. Thanks!